# JavaScript class to modify a paragraph using click handlers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create a JavaScript class "ModifyParagraph", here constructor accepts paragraph element. inside the constructor, create 4 buttons (which change the paragraph, Bold, color, size, position) using document.createElement and add click event handler on each. Click handler on bold button will turn on/off the boldness.

My code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question-2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="q2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="q2.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="myDIV" style="width:500px; ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porttitor ut donec ut egestas, purus urna consectetuer, arcu et vitae elementum nulla etiam in, sit leo lacus. Ligula cras tortor dignissim laoreet ut, nonummy hendrerit mauris, vitae augue congue congue, vel et augue, eros at. Fringilla id donec libero mauris eleifend. Nulla nunc sit. Consequat sodales placerat faucibus mauris, urna lectus vitae, sit nisl laoreet libero at suscipit ut, neque laoreet dapibus sapien. Sodales sit ut metus commodo tellus, ultricies cursus, et faucibus vitae quam, sit ultrices rhoncus. Massa duis mauris arcu vulputate, iste orci porttitor a ac, quisque venenatis pellentesque in in velit sed, repellat lorem consectetur vero, urna tellus donec. Suscipit in, donec beatae, lectus bibendum morbi justo consectetuer ac, facilisis metus vel non sapien vel. Magna congue vitae quia nulla nulla, lorem enim urna augue et et, sem morbi lorem ornare velit neque morbi, erat id et blandit iaculis.</div>

    </body>

    </ul>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
class ModifyParagraph{
    constructor(myDIV){
        this.myDIV = myDIV;
    function myFunction(){
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var bold = document.getElementById(myDIV);
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if (bold.style['font-weight']) {
                bold.style.removeProperty('font-weight');
              } else {
                bold.style['font-weight'] = "800";
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

In my code, I have a problem in creating a button inside the constructor and adding click handlers on each button. Please let me know how to proceed

Comment: You have a `div.style` in EventListener. What's the `div` or you missing some code.

Comment: You're defining a function inside the constructor but not calling it.

Comment: I modified it, its bold.style

Comment: My code does not create a button as well as any functionality. i don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from your syntax mistakes(I'll cover them later in the answer), your main issue is that you missed to append the created `button` to the `DOM`.

Here's a working demo:

```js
class ModifyParagraph {
  constructor(div) {
    this.myDIV = div;
  }
  toggleBoldStyle() {
    // create the button.
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    // give it some text/value.
    btn.textContent = 'toggle Bold styling';
    // add click event listener to the button.
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // if the font-weight is 800 make it 'normal' else if it's other than 800 make it 800'
      // add the 'this' keyword in the addEventListener method references the button, to get the member myDIV we'll just call it without preceding it by 'this'(myDIV in place of this.myDIV).
      myDIV.style.fontWeight = (myDIV.style.fontWeight === '800') ? 'normal':'800';
    });
    // append the button to the DOM
    this.myDIV.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
// testing...
var p = new ModifyParagraph(document.getElementById('myDIV'));
p.toggleBoldStyle();
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" style="width:500px; ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porttitor ut donec ut egestas, purus urna consectetuer, arcu et vitae elementum nulla etiam in, sit leo lacus. Ligula cras tortor dignissim laoreet ut, nonummy hendrerit mauris, vitae augue congue congue, vel et augue, eros at. Fringilla id donec libero mauris eleifend. Nulla nunc sit. Consequat sodales placerat faucibus mauris, urna lectus vitae, sit nisl laoreet libero at suscipit ut, neque laoreet dapibus sapien. Sodales sit ut metus commodo tellus, ultricies cursus, et faucibus vitae quam, sit ultrices rhoncus. Massa duis mauris arcu vulputate, iste orci porttitor a ac, quisque venenatis pellentesque in in velit sed, repellat lorem consectetur vero, urna tellus donec. Suscipit in, donec beatae, lectus bibendum morbi justo consectetuer ac, facilisis metus vel non sapien vel. Magna congue vitae quia nulla nulla, lorem enim urna augue et et, sem morbi lorem ornare velit neque morbi, erat id et blandit iaculis.</div>
```

Apart from missing to append the `button` to the `DOM`, you had some mistakes:

- Class methods doesn't require the 'function' keyword, you have to just write the method name.
- You missed a closing parenthesis of the `addEventListener` method.
- Why you're trying to get the element that you just saaved in the `muyDIV` member. Better, you have two choices: send the element itself to the constructor or send it's `ID` and in the assignment to the `myDIV` member you fetch the element by the `getElementById` method. In my demo I sent the element itself to the constructor. But, you can make things more complicated to allow sending the `ID` or the element itself possible, innthe constructor you have to check the type of the incoming argument.

Finally, here's the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) of the MDN documentation of the ECMAScript 5 classes.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Thank-you. @ths. However, when I try to run this in the browser, the console shows an uncaught type error at  this.myDIV.appendChild(btn);. I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: that's the same as the snippet is executed by the browser, then the problem relies in your code, would you paste it ?

Comment: please see the answer that I uploaded.

Comment: is the "q2.js" the file where you putted my answer ? If yes, then place its script tag just before `</bofy>`.

Answer (score 0):

My code,
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question-2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="q2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="myDIV" style="width:500px; ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porttitor ut donec ut egestas, purus urna consectetuer, arcu et vitae elementum nulla etiam in, sit leo lacus. Ligula cras tortor dignissim laoreet ut, nonummy hendrerit mauris, vitae augue congue congue, vel et augue, eros at. Fringilla id donec libero mauris eleifend. Nulla nunc sit. Consequat sodales placerat faucibus mauris, urna lectus vitae, sit nisl laoreet libero at suscipit ut, neque laoreet dapibus sapien. Sodales sit ut metus commodo tellus, ultricies cursus, et faucibus vitae quam, sit ultrices rhoncus. Massa duis mauris arcu vulputate, iste orci porttitor a ac, quisque venenatis pellentesque in in velit sed, repellat lorem consectetur vero, urna tellus donec. Suscipit in, donec beatae, lectus bibendum morbi justo consectetuer ac, facilisis metus vel non sapien vel. Magna congue vitae quia nulla nulla, lorem enim urna augue et et, sem morbi lorem ornare velit neque morbi, erat id et blandit iaculis.</div>

    </body>

    </ul>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
    class ModifyParagraph {
  constructor(div) {
    this.myDIV = div;
  }
  toggleBoldStyle() {
    // create the button.
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    // give it some text/value.
    btn.textContent = 'toggle Bold styling';
    // add click event listener to the button.
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // if the font-weight is 800 make it 'normal' else if it's other than 800 make it 800'
      // add the 'this' keyword in the addEventListener method references the button, to get the member myDIV we'll just call it without preceding it by 'this'(myDIV in place of this.myDIV).
      myDIV.style.fontWeight = (myDIV.style.fontWeight === '800') ? 'normal':'800';
    });
    // append the button to the DOM
    this.myDIV.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
// testing...
var p = new ModifyParagraph(document.getElementById('myDIV'));
p.toggleBoldStyle();
```